# Reshuffling the adjacency matrix of an undirected random graph based on connectivity

Tags: matlab, graph, adjacency-matrix

I have a `n`x`n` adjacency matrix `A` of an undirected random graph, so `Aij` can be either *0* or *1*. If `Aij` is  *1* that means there is an edge between *`i`th* and *`j`th* node. If it is *0* that means there is no edge between them.

I want to reshuffle the matrix based the degree of the vertices. All the vertices which have degree less than equal to *`k`*, I want to put them at the end. Let say there are *`m`* such vertices, so last *`m`* rows and columns of my new adjacency matrix will represent these vertices.

I want to implement this in MATLAB. I have no idea how to solve it efficiently. Just one think I know how to find such vertices.

```
a = 1:n;
ver = a(sum(A) < k+1 );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your graph is undirected, your adjacency matrix `A` is symmetric. As you already noted you can tell the degree of the vertices simply by summing the rows (or columns) of `A`:

```
deg = sum(A, 2);
```

Now you can [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) the vertices based on their degree

```
[sd si] = sort(deg, 'decrease'); %// sort in a decreasing order
```

You can use the sorted indices (`si`) to re-arrange `A`:

```
A = A(si,si);
```

Note that you *MUST* apply the same permutation to both rows and columns of `A`, otherwise...

Now that your graph is ordered by the degree of vertices the once with smaller degree would naturally be at the end of `A`.

Comment: Well spotted about applying the same permutation to columns!

Comment: Yes. Nice one. I completely overlooked the sorting possibility based on the connectivity. Thanks again.